# How to parse text to dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

Let's imagine that I have a text like this:

```
if last_n_input_time <= 7463.0:
      else: if last_n_input_time > 7463.0
    else: if passwd_input_time > 27560.0
  else: if secret_answ_input_time > 7673.5
    if first_n_input_time <= 4054.5:
      if passwd_input_time <= 5041.0:
      else: if passwd_input_time > 5041.0
    else: if first_n_input_time > 4054.5
      return [[ 1.01167029]]
....
```

And I have a dataframe with such columns as passwd_input_time, first_n_input_time and others - named in the same way as variables in the text.

The question is how can I search for example for first_n_input_time and if I find it in the text, then move to another symbol and see whether it's > or <= and then cut out the value which goes after > or <= symbols and add it to the cell of my dataframe.

df['first_n_input_time'] = 4079 should the result of my function.
I understand how to find the world but I don't know how to cut the lines in such a way so I could get, for example, "secret_answ_input_time <= 7673.5" and then operate on it.

Example:
I want to cut out "if passwd_input_time <= 47635.5" at first. Find whether "password_input_time" it belongs to the list of column names of my dataframe (yes, it does). Then I need to move next and to check what the symbol is here "<=" or ">". If it's "<=" then I take the value 47635.5 and write to the cell of df['password_input_time_1']. If it's ">" then I write the value to another column df['password_input_time_2']

Here are some pieces of code I wrote trying to implement this but I'm stuck a bit cos I don't know how to move to the next word in the text:

```
def to_dataframe(i, str)
for word in str_.split():
    if any(word in s for s in cols_list):
        #move to the next word somehow
        #I will call it next_word later on for simplicity
        col_name = word #save the value to refer to it later
        if next_word == "<=":
            col_name.append('_1')
            #move to the value somehow
            #I will call it 'value' later on
            df[col_name][i] = value
        if next_word == ">"
            col_name.append('_2')
            #move to the value somehow
            #I will call it 'value' later on
            df[col_name][i]= value
```

Where cols_list is list of columns names of my dataframe.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? I don't really understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Can you show an example of the code you're currently using?

Comment: @patrick I've added an example to the end of the post so it would be more understandable.

Comment: So essentially you are trying to index a dataframe based on several conditions? E.g. make a call to return only the rows where _pw_input_time_ is less/equal than X, etc. ?

Comment: You've added more conditions to it, but you haven't added any example of what you've tried.  Are `<=` and `>` the only possible states?  Are you open to using regular expressions?  Should the new row in the dataframe correspond to the whole text?  What if a label appears multiple times in the text?

Comment: @patrick I am trying to fill the dataframe with values which are stored in the text with the names of the columns they(values) correspond to.

Comment: @ASGM give me a sec, I will add some code. <= and > are the only open states. The row in dataframe should not correspond to the whole text. When I meet 'return I should start adding new values to the next row in my dataframe even if not all cells in the previous row were filled with values